# Printing array in parent-child relationship

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, postgresql

I have an array of task ids that I fetch from database using postgres stored procedure. Here is my array:

```
  $relationships=array(
            array(70),//This represents calculated hierarchy field in a record
            array(70, 71),//This represents calculated hierarchy field in a record
            array(70, 71, 72),//This represents calculated hierarchy field in a record
            array(70, 71, 72, 68)//This represents calculated hierarchy field in a record
        );
```

I want to print them in table of contents format to be able to create XML file for MS Project.

This array should print indexes like this:

```
  $relationships=array(
            array(70),//Should print 1 because its grandparent task
            array(70, 71),//Should print 1.1 because its child of task 70
            array(70, 71, 72),//Should print 1.1.1 because its child of task 71
            array(70, 71, 72, 68)//Should print 1.1.1.1
        );
```

Any help?
I have been stuck since two days. 
Thanks

Comment: When it should print 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, ...?

Comment: When the task is grand parent it will print 1, when the task is immediate child it will print 1.1 and when the task is grandchild then it should print 1.1.1

Comment: I don't understand any of what you've asked.

Comment: I have a table of tasks having self relation. I have calculated the hierarchy based on their IDs in postgressql and each record contains serialized array of hierarchy for example array(70,71). Now I want to print them as table of contents format like 70,71 should be printed at 1.1

Comment: Did you mean something [like this](https://3v4l.org/Z2Sb3)

Comment: OR Did you mean something [like this](https://3v4l.org/Qjiab)

Comment: @FrayneKonok quite close but when new root is added index is not incrementing. See this: https://3v4l.org/iZGjo

Comment: You need the new one as `2`??

Comment: Yes when array contains only 1 element then index should be incremented. I want to accomplish table of contents functionality using arrays. Each subsequent element of the array is child of earlier one. And if element has no child then its next root element (next chapter). Thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112171/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-user3445122).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/i17B1), This is the checking link for testing purpose.

```
$relationships=array(
            array(70),
            array(70, 71),
            array(70, 71, 72),
            array(70, 71, 72, 68),
            array(80)
        );
$old_count = 0;
$index = 0;
foreach($relationships as $val){    
    $tmp = array();
    $value = array();
    $count = count($val);
    if($count == 1){
        $old_count = 0;
        $level = array();       
        $index++;
        $level[] = $index;
    }

    if($old_count == $count)
        $level[($count-1)] = ($level[($count-1)] == "" || $level[($count-1)] == null) ? 1 : ++$level[($count-1)];
    else if($old_count > $count){
        $level[($count-1)] = ($level[($count-1)] == "" || $level[($count-1)] == null) ? 1 : ++$level[($count-1)];
        for($j = $count; $j <= $old_count; $j++)
            $level[$j] = 1;
    }
    else
        $level[$count] = 1; 

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $tmp[] = $level[$i];
    }
    $old_count = $count;
    echo "Indexes: ".implode(".", $tmp)."<br/>";
```

**Result:**

```
Indexes: 1
Indexes: 1.1
Indexes: 1.1.1
Indexes: 1.1.2
Indexes: 1.2
Indexes: 2
Indexes: 2.1
Indexes: 2.1.1
Indexes: 2.1.2
Indexes: 2.1.2.1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Let me try that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Richard's answer is good as well but I could accept only one. So I upvoted him. Thanks

Comment: @user3445122, Nope, His answer has some drawback. Rony's answer is also well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$relationships = array(
    array(70, 71, 72),      // 1.1.1
    array(80),              // 2
    array(75, 71, 72),      // 3.1.1
    array(80, 72),          // 2.1
    array(75, 72, 72),      // 3.2.1
    array(70),              // 1
    array(70, 71, 74),      // 1.1.2
    array(80, 71, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),           // 2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
    array(80, 71, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0)            // 2.2.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.2
);

function find_all($values, &$arr){
    if(count($values) == 0){
        echo "\n"; return;
    }
    if(array_key_exists($values[0], $arr))
        echo (array_search($values[0], array_keys($arr))+1).'.';
    else {
        echo (count($arr)+1).'.';
        $arr[$values[0]] = array();
    }
    find_all(array_slice($values, 1), $arr[$values[0]]);
}

$storage = array();
foreach($relationships as $array)
    find_all($array, $storage);
```

Comment: Feel free to use my $relationships array to test other answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to understand the spec and I've come up with simple solution

```
$relationships=array(
    array(70),//Should print 1 because its grandparent task
    array(70, 71),//Should print 1.1 because its child of task 70
    array(70, 71, 72),//Should print 1.1.1 because its child of task 71
    array(70, 71, 72, 68),//Should print 1.1.1.1
    array(70, 71, 72, 69),//Should print 1.1.1.2
    array(70, 73), //Should print 1.2

);

$parents = array();

foreach($relationships as $row) {
    // parsing row
    $row_output = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++)
    {

        if(!isset($parents[$i]))
            $parents[$i] = array();

        $index = array_search($row[$i], $parents[$i]);
        if($index !== FALSE) {
            $row_output[] = $index+1;
        }
        else {
            $index = count($parents[$i]);
            $parents[$i][] = $row[$i];
            $row_output[] = $index+1;
        }
    }
    echo implode('.', $row_output) . "\n";
}

// var_export($parents);
```

the $parents is listing all the parents on each level. So if there's a different number that algorithm already know, it will add an item and use it as next index (based on already present items) in $parent[$i]

Comment: Looks quite good..I will test in different scenarios.If it works good then I will mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot for your help.